# Quip Live App Approval and QA process

Tags: quip, liveapps

Our team is beginning work on a new Live App, and would like a reference to any documentation regarding the QA and Approval process to be listed in the AppExchange at a later date.

Has Quip published any best practices for new projects to follow so we can work towards approval and getting published in AppExchange? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Great to hear your team is considering publishing to the AppExchange. You can find documentation here: https://www.quipsupport.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002102492-Publish-Quip-Live-Apps-on-the-Salesforce-AppExchange